# Gower Distance Formula for KNN

Tags: machine-learning, similarity

I'm trying to add Gower distance for my KNN implementation but I can't find out the formula for Gower distance. What is the formula for Gower distance?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298870/implementation-of-the-gower-distance-function

Answer (score 3):

The formula is defined in section two of Gower's [A general coefficient of similarity and some of its properties](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.412.4155).

> **Abstract**
>   A general coefficient measuring the similarity between two sampling units is defined. The matrix of similarities between all pairs of sample units is shown to be positive semidefinite (except possibly when there are missing values). This is important for the multidimensional Euclidean representation of the sample and also establishes some inequalities amongst the similarities relating three individuals. The definition is extended to cope with a hierarchy of characters.